# Angular modal window function not working properly

Tags: php, angularjs, angularjs-directive, partial, modal-window

I have an Angular function within a PHP partial page that appears to not be working properly. The function is attached to all images that are loaded on to the page from a MySQL database, and is called with `ng-click="vm.openModal('custom-modal-1')"`.

```
<div id="screenings">
    <?php
    ...
    //connect to MySQL database
    ...
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<div class='img_div'>";?>

                //here is the ng-click that calls the Angular function

                <img class="modal_img img_screenings" ng-click="vm.openModal('custom-modal-1')" src='images/<?php echo $row['image']."' >";
            ...
            echo "</div>";
        }
    ?>

</div>

//here is the modal with the id that gets passed to the Angular function

<modal id="custom-modal-1">
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-body">
                <img id="popup_img" src="#">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-background"></div>
</modal>
```

Within the file app.js, here is the function that I'm trying to call:

```
app.controller('screeningsController', ['$scope', '$log', "ModalService", function($scope, $log, ModalService){

    var vm = this;

    //outputs "Hello World!" to browser console as a test
    vm.message = "Hello World!";
    $log.log(vm.message);

    vm.openModal = openModal;
    vm.closeModal = closeModal;

    function openModal(id){
        ModalService.Open(id);
    }

    function closeModal(id){
        ModalService.Close(id);
    }

}]);
```

When the partial page is loaded in, the test message "Hello World!" that is found within the Angular function fires, and the message appears in the browser console. However, the `ng-click` doesn't do anything else when any `img` with class `modal_img` is clicked on the page.

All Angular modal window materials for this code was taken from: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/07/13/angularjs-custom-modal-example-tutorial

**EDIT** `Controller as` is declared at the top of the app.js file, like so:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ui.router']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

 $stateProvider

 .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'pages/main.html',
    controller: 'mainController',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
 })

 .state('screenings', {
    url: '/screenings',
    templateUrl: 'pages/screenings.php',
    controller: 'screeningsController',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
 })

 //etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `ng-click="vm.openModal('custom-modal-1')"` to work you need to define what is `vm`.

In AngularJS a template expression is evaluated in the angular scope.

So you will need to tell the template that you intend to use `screeningsController`.

It is like defining a variable/object instance in a block of code up so that the code block can use that.

Only then the template can use the controller functions or scope functions.

So there are two ways how you can expose controller properties/functions.

1) By populating functions and variables on $scope
2) By populating the controller function using `this` like you used var `vm = this;`

In your case your `vm.openModal` will be available to every element under `id="screenings"` if you declare that HTML element as below.

`<div ng-controller="screeningsController" id="screenings">`

However in order to user controller function populated on `this` one must use `controller as` syntax. So the above line becomes this:

`<div ng-controller="screeningsController as vm" id="screenings">`

In the above line you are saying that `vm` is `screeningsController`.

It is best to use something more meaningful than just `vm` in case you end up using more than 1 controller say nested controllers.

So one might just call `vm` as what it is - in this case `screeningsController`

`<div ng-controller="screeningsController as screeningsController" id="screenings">`
and the ng-click becomes 
`ng-click="screeningsController.openModal('custom-modal-1')"`

If  `screeningsController as screeningsController` feels weird I would change that to `ScreeningsController as screeningsController` where by you are essentially saying screeningsController is ScreeningsController. 
Hence you might want to define `app.controller('screeningsController'` as 
rather
`app.controller('ScreeningsController'`

Its like giving a name to the Controller class/constructor so why not start with Capital case.

You can checkout [official Angular ngController documentation and the example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)

Most of what I have recommended is for following best conventions. If everything else is correct your problem should just get resolved merely by
`<div ng-controller="screeningsController as vm" id="screenings">`

You may place ngController at other appropriate places but it must be some ancestor to your ng-click which needs access to that controller.

Comment: Thank you for the incredibly thorough answer..someone was telling me about the difference between `this` and `$scope`, but this was a bit more thorough, so I appreciate that. Unfortunately `<div ng-controller="screeningsController as vm" id="screenings">` did not seem to fix it, though the test message `"Hello World!"` seems to fire twice now.

Comment: The tutorial doesn't appear to be using `ng-controller as` in their page either.

Comment: Actually, he posts it when he declares his states - let me update my question with this code.

Comment: I suggest that you copy the HTML from browser after PHP has rendered from the server . Best is create a plnkr out of that HTML from browser - with small tweaking problem can be reproduced and fixed quite fast.

Comment: Partial PHP page is loaded within `<ui view></ui view>`

Comment: I see module error in browser console. It is saying that `app` is not a module this is due to many files getting 404 and not being fetched. e.g.  ` <script src="javascript/scripts.js"></script>
 
 <!--angular app-->
 <script src="javascript/app.js"></script>
 <script src="javascript/modal.service.js"></script>
 <script src="javascript/modal.directive.js"></script>`

Comment: These file need to be added to the plnkr.

Comment: Sorry, I'm terrible at using plunker. One moment.

Comment: Okay, my apologies. All four of those should be in there now.

Comment: Would it help if I prepared a plunker with a working example from the tutorial?

Comment: Tried to fix your plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/mJvhii7Mb9vUt281gY6N?p=preview but it seems there are fundamental differenrces in the example. You have everything moved to  index,html. main.html was missing so I moved some content to main.html. Probably creating plnkr f the example might be best.

Comment: thank you for all your help. I will do that and get back to you.

Comment: I feel like maybe my less.js is not working properly

Comment: Ah it was the less.js!!!!!! I finally got it working after a week of not knowing what was going on. I'm accepting your answer anyway. God bless America.